# Variavel Char não esta recebendo valores em C

Tags: c, char

Boa tarde pessoal

minha variavel char z não está funcionando nem com o scanf_s e nem com gets_s. Com o scanf ela gera uma exceção e trava o programa, usando o gets_s no momento de entrar com os dados ele pula direto para o final do código. Alguem pode me ajudar? Já tentei usar o código de limpeza do buffer do teclado e também não dá certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    //Declaração das variáveis, dos ponteiros e inicialização dos ponteiros.
    int x;
    float y;
    char z[10];

    //Momento em que o usúário digita os valores iniciais para as variáveis.
    printf("Digite um número inteiro a ser atribuido à variável x: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    printf("Digite um número real a ser atribuído à variável y: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &y);
    printf("Digite uma letra a ser atribuída à variável z: ");
    gets_s(z);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar a função de get assim:

```
char ch;

   printf("Digite algum caracter: ");

   ch = getchar();

   printf("\n A tecla pressionada eh %c.\n", ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça dessa forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    //Declaração das variáveis, dos ponteiros e inicialização dos ponteiros.
    int x;
    float y;
    char z[10];

    //Momento em que o usúário digita os valores iniciais para as variáveis.
    printf("Digite um número inteiro a ser atribuido à variável x: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    printf("Digite um número real a ser atribuído à variável y: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &y);
    
    printf("Digite uma letra a ser atribuída à variável z: ");
    scanf_s("%s",&z);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Não é `scanf_s("%s",&z);` e sim `scanf_s("%s", z);`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    //Declaração das variáveis, dos ponteiros e inicialização dos ponteiros.
    int x;
    float y;
    char z[10];

    //Momento em que o usúário digita os valores iniciais para as variáveis.
    printf("Digite um número inteiro a ser atribuido à variável x: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    printf("Digite um número real a ser atribuído à variável y: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &y);
    printf("Digite uma letra a ser atribuída à variável z: ");
    scanf("%c", &z);
 
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoa atualizando o post, a solução que encontrei foi limpar o buffer do teclado, embaixo de cada scanf eu adicionei a seguinte linha:

while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n') {}

obs: necessário declarar a váriavel char c.